# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Application (unknown member) : Failed

Tags: c#, .net, office365, powerpoint, office-interop

After updating to office version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/semi-annual-enterprise-channel#version-2002-january-12

On some of the machines `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass.Quit()` is failing with following error : `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Application (unknown member) : Failed.    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass.Quit()`

It works when at least one PPT is already open.

Comment: It is difficult to say exactly why the problems happen, however, the key comment is… _”After updating to office version”_ … This is important and can cause problems with “existing” applications using Interop. If ALL the machines have been “updated,” then, you will need to re-reference and re-compile ALL the apps using Interop with the newer versions of the updated Office libraries. If some but not all the computers have been updated, then the non-updated computers should still work. This is one advantage of using a third-party Office library.